# Можно ли склонять слова автоматически в excel?

Tags: excel

Мне надо просклонять словосочетания, по падежам.

Возможно ли как-то автоматически это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Склонять можно, но если есть таблица соответствий. Т.е. фактически не склонение, а поиск соответствующей фразы. Как вариант - использовать внешние (И-нет) ресурсы, но это уже не в самом *Excel*

Answer (score 0):

Справился с помощью !SEMTools правда пришлось купить.